# How to allocate more space alongside Windows

Tags: partition

I installed Ubuntu on an old laptop, alongside WinXP. Now I'm trying to download some updates and it says that I don't have enough free disk space - I need to free some more space on "/".

Since there's plenty of room on the machine, I suppose it means that not enough space is allocated for the Ubuntu partition itself, right? How can I solve this?

<sub>I'm a Windows guy who hasn't so much as seen a Linux desktop up until about an hour ago.</sub>

UPD

Apparently it's installed in the same partition as Windows. At least, I don't remember it asking me about space allocation during installation, and when I log into Windows I can see that the disk only has one partition. I do remember it saying something about reduced disk performance if I chose a specific option - and that's the one I chose :).

Comment: Hi, Vitaly - welcome! You understand it correctly. But you'd need to give more details about how your drive is now partitioned before someone can help you out.

Comment: Did you install in a separate partition or inside a magic file saved in the Windows partition?

Comment: @Vitaly Mijiritsky: you might have to reinstall Ubuntu in it's own partition.

Comment: I second Caleb's recommendation on using the GParted live CD. If you want more help here, we need to know how your disk is partitioned. The easiest way for you to tell us that is to run the command `sudo fdisk -l` in a terminal, and copy-paste the output.

Comment: Thanks guys, I reinstalled it in a separate partition, and it solved it. More noob questions to come :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This answer assumes you installed in a separate partition on the same drive with your Windows partition.)

You should look into using a program like `gparted` to resize your partions and the file-systems inside them. Since this operation is very difficult to do from a running system, I suggest you use the [GParted LiveCD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) (There are also LiveUSB versions on their site). This will allow you to boot up to a separate software stack without mounting any drives and edit your partition scheme and re-size the file systems.

Comment: Note that for a beginner, there are many things that can go wrong. Especially, if resizing the Windows partition is necessary. (One may not be able to boot into Windows sometimes, for example.)